# emulator: ERROR: Can't get kernel version from the kernel image file

Tags: android

When I finished compiling the source code of Android 11, I was informed after executing the emulator command.

Detail:
emulator: ERROR: Can't get kernel version from the kernel image file: 'prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm64/ranchu/kernel-qemu'

Thank you to every warm-hearted friend.

Answer (score 1):

Try

lunch aosp_x86_64-eng

I came across the same problem, and it worked for me.